# Java method calls

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Date;
 public class Example {
  public static void main(String args[]) {

        Date d1 = new Date (99, 11, 31);
        Date d2 = new Date (99, 11, 31);

        method(d1, d2);
        System.out.println("d1 is " + d1+ "\nd2 is " + d2);
  }

  public static void method(Date d1, Date d2) {

        d2.setYear (100);
        d1 = d2;
  }

 }
```

The above code works fine. an output is

```
d1 is Fri December 31 00:00:00 GMT 1999
d2 is Sun December 31 00:00:00 GMT 2000
```

But when I use wrapper class like Integer in a simialr method the change is not reflected.why?

Comment: show the code using Integers.

Comment: `code` Integer d1=new Integer(10); Integer d2=new Integer(20); meth(d1,d2); System.out.println("d1 is " + d1 + "\nd2 is " + d2);} public static void meth(Integer x,Integer y){ y=90;}

Comment: oh i dint know wrapper classes are immutable.Thanks amit.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `d1` doesn't get changed by that method, even 'though you assign `d1 = d2`. This is because the `d1` inside the method is a *copy of the reference* stored in `d1` in Main.

The only real modification you do is the call to `setYear`, which modifies the object referenced by `d2`.

Since `Integer` is immutable (i.e. `Integer` objects can't be changed once they are created), there is no way to do a manipulation like this. Simply assigning a new value to `d1` or `d2` inside the method will have no effect on `d1` and `d2` inside `main`.

All of this might get less confusing when you call the parameters of your method differently from your variables in `main`. That would make it clearer that they are **not related in any way**.

Answer (score 0):

Integer wrapper is immutable so there is no way you can do any modification to that object